# Choosing a prime for discrete logarithm

Tags: discrete-logarithm, prime-numbers

When choosing a prime for discrete logarithm problem it is advised not to choose a prime of form $p\equiv3\bmod4$.

Are there any other restrictions such as smoothness of $p-1$?

Comment: Related: [Are safe primes $p=2^k \pm s$ with $s$ small less recommandable than others as a discrete log modulus?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1386/13625)

Comment: [p-1 had better _not_ be smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig–Hellman_algorithm). ​ ​

Comment: Where is that advise to have $p\equiv3\bmod4$ worded?