# In end-to-end encryption, doesn't the server need to be trusted?

Tags: encryption, public-key, key-exchange

Applications like WhatsApp use end to end encryption. WhatsApp says that only the users share a specific key and no third party can view the messages. But I do not understand how the two users agree on the shared key. It must have been transferred via WhatsApp servers. In that way, WhatsApp would know the shared key right? Please help me understand how keys are shared in end to end encryption.

Comment: Do the participants require a "shared key"? I would expect they would each only require the other one's public key.

Comment: Typically for things like this users exchange a shared secret using asymmetric  encryption and then use that shared key for all subsequent communication. Reason being that shared key encryption/decryption is typically faster.

Comment: My question is regarding how the shared key is transfered initially. How does the recipients agree on the key in the first place?

Comment: What research have you done? The google keyword [share keys](https://www.google.de/search?q=share+keys) already points towards the Wikipedia article [key distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_distribution). Also: The title does not reflect the question. Key agreement is just a tiny part of creating a secure protocol (there's a difference between safety and security, you mean *secure*).

Comment: Given that this question is in the context of WhatsApp, in addition to the existing security/abuse concerns regarding Facebook, who owns WhatsApp, I think the article [WhatsApp ordered to stop sharing user data with Facebook](https://www.theverge.com/2017/12/18/16792448/whatsapp-facebook-data-sharing-no-user-consent) is likely to be relevant.

Comment: There is a great technical whitepaper published by WhatsApp itself on how it functions internally, might want to check it out. https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf

Comment: For Symmetrical cryptography where each party uses the same key take a look at [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) this allows a secret to be worked out over an insecure network without eavesdroppers being able to know what the secret is.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

End-to-end *encryption* over a channel with an eavesdropper, like the WhatsApp server, works by using a mathemagical spell called Diffie–Hellman key agreement.  What follows is not actually how WhatsApp works,* but explores some of the high-level ideas to concretely answer the question without getting lost in the full gory details of everything about the protocol, which defends against many more threats than what you asked about.

Alice and Bob agree on public parameters $p$ and $g$,<sup>†</sup> say $$p = 2^{2048} - 2^{1984} - 1 + 2^{64} (\lfloor2^{1918}\pi\rfloor + 124476)$$ and $g = 2$.  When Alice wants to have a conversation with Bob, she picks an integer $a$ with $0 \leq a < (p - 1)/2$ uniformly at random, computes the remainder after dividing $g^a$ by $p$,<sup>‡</sup> written $g^a \bmod p$, and transmits $g^a \bmod p$ over the channel.  Bob does similarly: picks $b$ uniformly at random in the same range, computes $g^b \bmod p$, and transmits $g^b \bmod p$ over the channel.

By a remarkable feat of mathematics, when Alice receives $g^b \bmod p$, she can compute $(g^b \bmod p)^a \bmod p$, and it turns out to be the same as $g^{ab} \bmod p$.  Bob does the same: given $g^a \bmod p$, computes $(g^a \bmod p)^b \bmod p$, and obtains the same number as $g^{ab} \bmod p$.

**Nobody has figured out the remarkable feat of mathematics that would allow someone who knows $g^a \bmod p$ and $g^b \bmod p$ *but not* $a$ or $b$ themselves to *also* compute $g^{ab} \bmod p$.**

Thus can Alice and Bob share a secret, $g^{ab} \bmod p$, over a channel without revealing to an eavesdropper what the secret is.  They will then hash this into a short secret key, say the 256-bit $k = \operatorname{SHA3-256}(g^{ab} \bmod p)$, perhaps with SHA3-256, and proceed to use it for symmetric-key encryption such as AES-CTR.

But that's not all.  What if it's not just an eavesdropper, but our friend Mallory who, aside from having an annoyingly ungendered name, actively intercepts messages in transit?  Mallory could *pretend* to be Bob to Alice, and Alice to Bob, and do a pair of Diffie–Hellman key agreements, and establish shared secrets with Alice and Bob, and then eavesdrop on all the messages they exchange.  The WhatsApp server is in a position to do this.

To thwart this subterfuge of *per-conversation shared secrets*, Alice and Bob use *long-term* authentication in addition.  Alice generates a number $\alpha$ just like $a$, and puts $g^\alpha \pmod p$ in the telephone book, or shows it to Bob on her phone screen; Bob does likewise with $\beta$.  Thus they have a long-term shared secret $\kappa = \operatorname{SHA3-256}(g^{\alpha \beta} \pmod p)$.  Now when Alice wants to have a conversation with Bob, she does the per-conversation protocol—but instead of transmitting just $g^a \bmod p$, she transmits $(g^a \bmod p, \operatorname{KMAC256}_\kappa(g^a \bmod p))$.

When Bob receives a candidate message $(A, t)$, he first checks whether $t = \operatorname{KMAC256}_\kappa(A)$ before processing it.  If not, he drops the message on the floor and ignores it.  Only Alice and Bob can compute the function $\operatorname{KMAC256}_\kappa$, because only Alice and Bob know the secret $\kappa$.

**Next, instead of just *encrypting* their actual conversation with $k = \operatorname{SHA3-256}(g^{ab} \bmod p)$ using AES-CTR, they encrypt *and authenticate* their conversation using AES-GCM.**  The WhatsApp server can flip bits in messages encrypted using AES-CTR without either Alice or Bob being any the wiser even though only Alice and Bob know the secret key, but without knowing the secret key, the WhatsApp server *cannot* change anything in messages encrypted *and authenticated* using AES-GCM without Alice and Bob noticing.

What if Alice and Bob can't exchange $g^\alpha \bmod p$ and $g^\beta \bmod p$ on their phone screens because they've never actually met in person?  They have to consult the telephone book—which WhatsApp publishes.  When Alice consults WhatsApp for Bob's long-term public identity key $g^\beta \bmod p$, WhatsApp could spoof it and lie about it, and if Alice ever *later* checks Bob's phone screen she will detect the subterfuge because it won't match the key that the WhatsApp server handed out.

On the other hand, if WhatsApp *does not* spoof Bob's long-term public identity in the telephone book, then Alice will *remember* it in her personal address book.  If the WhatsApp server ever tries to impersonate Bob when Alice tries to start a conversation, Alice will detect that.  This model of authentication is sometimes called **TOFU**, or **trust on first use**.  You will also find it in the ssh protocol.

There's a catch: **Sometimes Bob's identity key changes, like when he gets a new phone.  What should Alice do in that case?**  In [Signal](https://signal.org/), the app won't send any new messages on behalf of Alice; it will notify her that something is amiss and ask her what to do.  In WhatsApp, by default,<sup>§</sup> the app will automatically retry with the Bob's new identity key, in an attempt to reduce usability hurdles for users who don't understand this, which led to an [enormous kerfuffle](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/commentisfree/2017/jun/28/flawed-reporting-about-whatsapp) about mainstream media reporting of the choice, which somehow dwarfed a [much worse](https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/15/should-whatsapp-let-you-disable-url-previews/) vulnerability in the app leaking the text of what you were typing if it looked like a URL.

In the end, since WhatsApp—part of Facebook—provides the software and doesn't let you scrutinize it, they certainly have the power to read and impersonate your messages, which they probably think very earnestly they won't ever abuse.  That's better than letting *everyone* on the internet route between Alice and Bob, like the stalker who is sitting a few tables down at the coffee shop on the same wifi network as Alice, which is why it was so harmful for the Guardian to report breathlessly in a back door in WhatsApp the way it did.

Even if your phone spoke TLS to the WhatsApp servers with a pinned certificate, it's still easier to engineer audit trails for *malicious changes to the telephone book* than it is to engineer audit trails for *eavesdropping by the WhatsApp servers*—whether by a technical attacker exploiting a software vulnerability, by a LOVEINT disgruntled employee, or by a court-ordered wiretap.

So, can third parties read your WhatsApp messages?  No, not likely, and it would take an *active attack* by WhatsApp itself—similar to the kind that Apple refused to do for the FBI—for them to read your messages.

---

<sub>* WhatsApp claims to use the [Signal protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol) ([technical documentation](https://signal.org/docs/)).</sub>

<sub><sup>†</sup> Technical details: $p$ is a [*safe prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime), meaning it is a prime of the form $p = 2q + 1$ where $q$ is also prime.  $g$ is a [*quadratic residue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $p$, and thus has [*order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29) $q$, meaning there are $q$ distinct possible remainders of $g^x$ when divied by $p$ for any integer $x$.  The powers of $g$ modulo $p$ form a subgroup of the multiplicative group of integers $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$.  None of this is important for you to understand how to share secrets over a public channel, but I provide the keywords for you to follow if you want to study further.</sub>

<sub><sup>‡</sup> Alice does not actually compute, *e.g.*, 2^13805771959684693407656077397889219317288456747119690312451189306384849479687628613222950288427889322679415500741971589068616989911210949597114445259398229588157002772876797268276100622563299377498600497546320786879884333079126581727906347769889606788799518360227168951984468071470187490408276074397578464837282521956615118563389889631151319459158126320262667606793413409480951816493115818911703426164912115254095626026747790743791560327229116656590818054138360168383331595495242709153295834514181328053967320381842712608527965926684083141420258332671624779764031721576291538707703835661166957458717002972300906725181, and then divide the result by $p$; instead she uses a [*modular exponentiation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) algorithm so that it is possible to get an answer before the universe burns itself out.</sub>

<sub><sup>§</sup> Some of this is configurable: conscientious users who must use WhatsApp, like a journalist whose only contact with a source is WhatsApp, should [study WhatsApp's privacy and security options](https://medium.com/@mshelton/upgrading-whatsapp-security-386c8ce496d3).</sub>

Comment: Obnit: I believe the specific prime $p$ you give isn't actually safe for DH; the reason is that special form primes like that tend to be vulnerable to SNFS, which runs considerably faster than the standard NFS (GNFS) that we would use against most primes.  This is not meant to detract from your otherwise excellent answer

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?  I don't disbelieve you—I just obviously haven't kept up with finite-field DH for anything other than glib quips about mathemagical spells, because it's so full of sharp edges in practice.

Comment: TOFU is usually expanded to Trust On First Use. If you had a good reason to give a different expansion I suggest explaining it, otherwise I suggest correcting it.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage The prime you use here, is actually used by [Samuel Neves in his answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1389/23623) as an example for a prime that heavily favours SNFS.

Comment: Fantastic answer, however I'm still somewhat confused about the long-term authentication. If it's there purely to prevent WhatsApp from acting as a man-in-the-middle, surely the fact that WhatsApp is the one who publishes the 'phonebook' completely defeats the purpose of it? *Especially* since the app will not warn uses about mismatched keys, and instead use the new one (which can be spoofed at any time). What's the benefit here?

Comment: The Signal protocol also has various other properties, such as key erasure after each message with the double-ratchet, so that if you delete a message and a past network eavesdropper steals your phone, they still can't decrypt past network traffic.  WhatsApp adopted the protocol as a single package presumably because it was well-designed with _many_ useful security properties against real threat models, like the stalker at Alice's coffee shop. Does WhatsApp provide all the same properties as Signal? No, but re-engineering the ones it _does_ in a bespoke protocol would have been much harder.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct, and I've upvoted; however, I suspect that much of it will go over the OP's head.

Comment: From the little I know of WhatsApp , the receiver is not online when the sender sends a message. Therefore the principle used must be quite distant from DH.

Comment: @fgrieu You are right.  I didn't address anything about asynchronous messaging—which is why I pointed out that this isn't actually how the WhatsApp protocol works, although it uses the same general ideas in crypto.  _E.g._, it also doesn't use finite-field DH or SHA-3 at all, and there are signatures involved too, _etc._  You can read about the gory details—much too gory for this question and for a single crypto.se post—here: https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage Great answer. You perfectly answered my question. Also, Can Alice and Bob have the shared long term key only when they meet?

Comment: @AV94 In principle, they could take it, or a preimage-resistant hash of it, and write it down on paper, or copy it on their web site, or what have you.  In practice, the apps don't make this easy.  Of course, they could change at any moment.

Comment: Given that this answer uses WhatsApp for example purposes and also highlights the security/abuse concerns regarding Facebook, who owns WhatsApp, I think the article [WhatsApp ordered to stop sharing user data with Facebook](https://www.theverge.com/2017/12/18/16792448/whatsapp-facebook-data-sharing-no-user-consent) is likely to be relevant.

Comment: Is user key private key is stored on Whatsapp servers?

Comment: @Justas: If they implement the Signal protocol as they claim, no.  The secrets—like $a$, $\alpha$, $b$, $\beta$, $k$, and $\kappa$ in the illustrative protocol above—are all stored on the respective users' phones.  That's the point of the exercise: it's a mathemagical spell to share a secret like $k$ by exchanging only public information on an eavesdropped channel.

Comment: How about backups and restoring when user change a phone?

Comment: @Justas: I'm afraid that's outside the scope of the cryptography I can tell you about—you'll have to study other parts of how WhatsApp works, what kind of backups you're talking about, _etc._  In principle it should be possible to transfer a private key from one phone directly to another, but in practice apps (even Signal) don't tend to make this easy.  And of course you don't have the WhatsApp source code to verify any claims they might make about it.

Comment: Why in the world do you say *"That's better than letting everyone on the internet route between Alice and Bob"*? Wouldn't they still have TLS? Meaning WhatsApp is the one entity with the power to break this in both cases?

Comment: @Mehrdad The WhatsApp TLS front ends have to process very high volumes of traffic—the conversations of everyone on the planet using them.  These are very valuable targets for attack, immortalized in [the infamous NSA doodle about ‘SSL added and removed here’](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/nsa-infiltrates-links-to-yahoo-google-data-centers-worldwide-snowden-documents-say/2013/10/30/e51d661e-4166-11e3-8b74-d89d714ca4dd_story.html), and it's hard to put any sort of audit trail in them. A telephone book, while also high value, is not as high volume and admits audit trails.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: I don't see how being a valuable target for attack and potentially being hacked by the NSA translates into "*letting everyone on the internet route between Alice and BoB* see the traffic"?

Comment: @Mehrdad You're right—in principle, TLS is supposed to prevent that, and I glibly merged a number of different potentially relevant security concerns together into one not-entirely-true dichotomy of extremes: either full end-to-end encryption, or none at all.  One intermediate on the spectrum is TLS from Alice to WhatsApp to Bob.  The other routers on the internet can't usefully eavesdrop, but a government could compel WhatsApp to just passively record data, which is cheap.  With the full end-to-end system, WhatsApp would rather have to distribute lies in a publicly auditable telephone book.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: Yes I'm well aware of all that.

Comment: Heh, maybe you should use numeric footnotes instead of many seemingly arbitrary characters...

Answer (score 8):

There are different types of encryption.

- **Symmetric encryption**

This is where one key is used for encrypting and decrypting, often called a *shared secret*.  This is what many of us are familiar with from our time playing with codes (technically ciphers) as kids.

To use symmetric encryption (e.g. AES), we need to agree on the key beforehand, which is the catch.

- **Asymmetric encryption**

One key is used for encrypting, and another corresponding key is need for decryption.  The matching keys are referred to as a keypair, the encryption key as a public key and the decryption key as a private key.

When Alice wants to communicate to Bob secretly, she retrieves Bob's public key (which can be posted on the internet) and only Bob with his corresponding private key can read it.  This solves the problem of symmetric encryption of having to agree on secret first without anyone eavesdropping.

PGP uses asymmetric encryption to encrypt a random secret key used for symetic encryption of the message.  This hybrid use also avoids to problem of securely establishing a share secret first.

- There are also **Key Agreement Schemes**

These are similar to asymmetric encryption.  Instead of en and decryption however, they allow 2 users to establish a shared secret over an insecure channel (even if someone is eavesdropping).

The most common is Diffie–Hellman-Merkle.  The math involved on how and more importantly why it works is a bit heavy but have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Cryptographic_explanation .

---

Now, if WhatsApp used *symmetric* encryption alone, you'd be quite right in thinking that the key must have been sent over their server first and that it's not secure.  However, WhatsApp uses the signal protocol, which basically uses Diffie–Hellman to establish a shared secret session key which is then used for symmetric encryption (AES if I'm not mistaken). This allows secure end-to-end communication.

Comment: Aren't you missing a step where WhatsApp server may man-in-the-middle into DH?

Comment: @Cthulhu The signal protocol prevents MITM attacks using long term signing keys IINF.  I provided a very  simplified answer based on my interpretation of the OP's current state of knowledge. Great username by the way :-)

Answer (score 3):

Public-key cryptography allows precisely the sort of thing that's puzzling you: two parties can, over a public channel that eavesdroppers listen on, come up with a shared secret key. [“Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange” in plain English](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45963/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-in-plain-english) provides a few simplified explanations of this.  What this comes down to is that *if you and your contact **really** do have each others' public key* (which doesn't need to be confidential), then you can communicate over a public channel without being subject to eavesdroppers or message manipulation.

But that requires you and your contact to actually have each others' public key, a problem that WhatsApp can't completely solve on its own.  What WhatsApp provides in that front is what they call **security codes**, a mechanism that you and your contact can use to independently verify that you do have each other's correct public key, and not an impersonator's.  Using these security codes and *a trusted communications channel outside of WhatsApp* (critical!), you and your contact can verify that your devices have the correct key for each other.

[From the WhatsApp site](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28030015/?category=5245250):

> ## What is the "Verify security code" screen in the contact info screen?
>
> Each of your chats has its own security code used to verify that your
>   calls and the messages you send to that chat are end-to-end encrypted.
>
> **Note:** The verification process is optional and is used only to confirm
>   that the messages you send are end-to-end encrypted.
>
> This code can be found in the contact info screen, both as a QR code
>   and a 60-digit number. These codes are unique to each chat and can be
>   compared between people in each chat to verify that the messages you
>   send to the chat are end-to-end encrypted. Security codes are just
>   visible versions of the special key shared between you - and don't
>   worry, it's not the actual key itself, that's always kept secret.
>
> ## To verify that a chat is end-to-end encrypted
>
> 1. Open the chat.
> 2. Tap on the name of the contact to open the contact info screen.
> 3. Tap Encryption to view the QR code and 60-digit number.
>
> If you and your contact are physically next to each other, one of you
>   can scan the other's QR code or visually compare the 60-digit number.
>   If you scan the QR code, and the code is indeed the same, a green
>   checkmark will appear. Since they match, you can be sure no one is
>   intercepting your messages or calls.
>
> [...] If you and your contact are not physically near each other, you
>   can send them the 60-digit number. Let your contact know that once
>   they receive your code, they should write it down and then visually
>   compare it to the 60-digit number that appears in the contact info
>   screen under Encryption. For Android, iPhone and Windows Phone, you
>   can use the Share button from the QR code/60-digit number screen to
>   send the 60-digit number via SMS, email, etc.

WhatsApp describes this verification process as "optional," but if you don't verify your contacts' security codes (and do it *outside of WhatsApp*), then you are indeed trusting the server as you surmise.  What they offer is, broadly, the best that they can offer: a *tool* that you *can* use to independently verify they are doing what they claim.  But they can't actually force you to do that verification, that you have to do on your own.  The best they can do is make it easier to use (which they do with, e.g., the QR codes).

If this is something that bugs you in the least bit, you should get into the habit of verifying your contacts' security codes when you do meet them.  One of the principles of the Signal protocol (the protocol that WhatsApp uses, which it adopted from the [Signal Messenger](https://signal.org/) application) is that we need a minority of users to be vigilant about security codes in order to defend the bulk of users against indiscriminate mass surveillance.  If enough users do their part from time to time we can be confident that WhatsApp's servers are, at worst, being used only for *targeted surveillance* against narrow sets of users.

Answer (score 2):

End to End encryption is secure even if the channel is not secure, that is kind of point. You can also negotiate a key over an insecure channel.
WhatsApp uses the well reviewed https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol 
And it uses internally Diffi Hellman key exchange.
So if the clients implement the protocol correctly someone listening in can not get the negotiated key.

However we still need authentication. So we know who we are talking to. We still rely on Whatsapp for that, they hold public keys.
Whatsapp also provides the software for the clients and we need to trusr it did a compotent and honest job.
And the worst part is that on many devices the messages are encrypted in transit, stored in clear on the device which is then backed up to a Google or Apple servers. So even if WhatsApp can't read your messages. Google or Apple probably can.

Comment: Do you have a source of this storing of messages unencrypted and automatically backed up unencrypted?

Comment: Looking for a source, I see things changed a few months ago. So currently things aren't as bad as they used to be. There are still some issues with the backup encryption but at least it isn't as trivial as it used to be: https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/techcrunch.com/2017/05/08/whatsapp-quietly-added-encryption-to-icloud-backups/amp/

Answer (score 1):

End to end encryption safety depends on two elements (two of which were described above):

- The security of the encryption on each end device
- and the security of the key exchange algorithm

I suspect that the end devices are the weakest.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Did you mean to comment on an answer (whichever answer you're referring to by “above”)?

Answer (score 0):

End to end encryption(etee) works in such that Whatsapp is NOT involved.   If it were that would be Point to Point (ptpe) encryption.  In etee both parties establiah an mutual agreement on algos and such based on the lower common supported/allowed options, not too much unlike how you browser does with a webserver.

Comment: I suspect that you might need to go into how "mutual agreement algorithms" work, and how a man in the middle cannot listen in - I suspect AV94 doesn't understand that yet...

Comment: OP: i'll assume you do but if not i'll gladly link to info as @poncho alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the server, but the overall software system you're using has to be trusted.  Sure, the data may be encrypted and you might be able to verify that, but there is no way you can prove that the key isn't being leaked or deliberately communicated to some third party.

Comment: the point of end-to-end encryption is that the server need not be trusted at all, which answers the main question.  in end-to-end encryption, the client needs to be trusted.  as you say, a bad client can leak the keys.  but if it's correct end-to-end, the server can't leak your keys because it just doesn't have them.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to communicate securely if all communication goes through an untrusted intermediary, as the intermediary could just pretend towards each party that it is the other party (the [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)). So assuming that the parties cannot / don't want to communcate directly, even to the extent of swapping keys, the server does need to be trusted somewhat.

On the other hand, there are various asymmetric encryption schemes (described in detail in the other answers) which are secure as long as the intermediary does not actively interfere in the communication (ie. secure under the assumption that the server might eavesdrop on the messages but will forward them faithfully). Since interference can easily be detected if the parties do talk directly, so it is risky for an attacker to attempt, it is not too much of a concern in practice.

Answer (score -3):

What you really need is to make sure your public key and the other partys is actually transmitted correctly. **The only way to make this sure is to hand over the public key personally and physically on a device you trust, preferrably analog** . The technology clearly exists (as in I could do it technologically speaking if I wanted to) to adaptively in transit over the open internet switch public keys for fake ones to allow for MITM attacks, if you just manage to bribe the right people.

---

And once you become a parent you will be ***very*** susceptible to bribes. Also most of the worlds voting population are parents, so good luck in changing any of that within the frames of democracy.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's also wrong. Look up [public key infrastructures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure).

Comment: You are right it does not answer the question. But how is it wrong? You don't need a public key infrastructure to do public key encryption. But if you do, stuff needs be transferred from and to the different RA, CA, VA in the diagram of the wikipedia page. What stops someone sitting on that wire to exchange what is being sent? You know there are several in-betweens on those black arrows on the internet, right?

Comment: With a suitable PKI, each node needs to start off with *one* public key, and everything else is protected from man-in-the-middle. In the case of WhatsApp, this bootstrap public key typically comes bundled with the phone (actually several public keys: the root CA keys for SSL, and maybe some keys built into the app installer). Then the trust propagates to the WhatsApp app, and from there to WhatsApp users.

Comment: @Gilles The public keys must be transmitted somehow to become publicly known. If they are transmitted publicly without encryption they could be altered in flight. You can never protect from such a man in the middle. You have to trust that (presumably unencrypted) channel where the public keys are made public. The only completely safe alternative is to physically exchange public keys with the person you want to communicate with so you know you get the right one.

Comment: Encryption is useless to transport public keys unless you want privacy. What's needed is authentication, and public-key cryptography lets you do that, with the confidence that nothing is altered in flight. As soon as you have the public key of one entity whom you trust to give you the public key of other entities, you can bootstrap trust. Man-in-the-middle attacks are a solved problem. PKI isn't, but the problem is who to trust, not how to communicate with whom you trust.

Comment: You really should read up on the basics of public-key cryptography, key agreement protocols (also called key exchange), and secure channels. [This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6290/how-is-it-possible-that-people-observing-an-https-connection-being-established-w) is a good start; it's focused on encryption but it's also useful to understand the authentication part. And [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Authentication is not a problem. It is built into public key cryptography. If you trust the public key to actually be from the one you want to communicate with, that is. You just need to make sure you got the *right* public key. Imagine the scenario where Bill who is in the middle of Alice and Ceasar identifies any public keys sent between them, does a find-replace on the key and sets himself up in the middle. Unless you trust the channel you transport the public keys on there is no way you can avoid that scenario and such Bills.

Comment: If there would be no issue with this, there would also be no reason to do manual physical public key exchanges by superdupernerds at cryptoparties. But those events do exist and it is what you have to do to be really paranoid-level-sure you got the right persons public key.

Answer (score -3):

If it's not end-to-end encrypted, it's not really encrypted at all!  Writing a ciphertext right next to a plaintext is equivalent information-wise to just writing the plaintext and deleting the ciphertext.  ie: Don't decrypt anything if it's decoded right in front of you.  Writing the keys next to the ciphertext is only a little better.  They will just combine the two to get the plaintext.  Encrypt-At-Rest is a little better in that the key isn't sitting on disk; but it usually means that the key does pass through that machine, and that machine could have written the key off somewhere (ie: to an S3 bucket of crypto keys).  End-To-End means that the machine has never seen the key, and does not perform encrypt/decrypt... that must hapen on a user's machine.

If you think about it, end-to-end is the only scenario in which you obeyed the first rule of crypto... to not give the key to somebody that isn't supposed to decrypt.  Encrypt-At-Rest that did have the key at some point relies on a gentleman's agreement to not simply remember the key or the ciphertext.

Comment: whoever thinks this comment is wrong somehow needs to explain how you actually know that, AWS for instance, isn't storing every key that you plug in to an S3 request header -  or remembering decrypted ciphertexts that are sent back.  You DONT know this.  Most of the time they aren't.  But giving your key to an untrusted system "for a short while" is, cryptographically speaking, nonsense.   There is no guarantee that the system will forget the key.  

Therefore, the security is reduced from an argument about entropy; to whether the gentleman's agreement is being honored.

Comment: The answer is very unclear. There is some system you have in your mind that is not communicated in the answer, it just seems to be a  disconnected stream of consciousness. Who are the actors. Ex: what does this mean: "Don't decrypt anything if it's decoded right in front of you." (no downvote—yet)

Comment: "In end-to-end encryption, doesn't the server need to be trusted?" - if the server needs to be trusted, then that's because it's seeing the key.  I am suggesting that if the server is able to decrypt your stuff; it isn't actually encrypted in the server.  So, I am asserting that end-to-end is another word for just "properly encrypted".  In the real world, people are letting AWS perform encrypt/decrypt, which gives AWS the key.  This is ok under the assumption that AWS forgets the key.  If AWS gets a national security letter, they have to comply with it. Not doing E2E provides the break.

Comment: a file being "encrypted" really means that the plaintext is absolutely unavailable to the unauthorized party; not that a ciphertext exists.  people store ciphertext in servers, and then write summaries of the ciphertext in plaintext right next to it.  they think it's encrypted because the ciphertext exists.  but it's not encrypted, because the plaintext is sitting right next to it in a slightly different form.

Comment: If someone gains unauthorised access to a AWS file server, or the server it-self is say stolen, the data is still encrypted and not readable without the key.  An email which is sent over TLS/StartTLS (by both outgoing and receiving mail host) is still encrypted and cannot be read by an eavesdropper on the network. Now, end-to-end encryption is indeed the best method for security and privacy. However, statements like "If it's not end-to-end encrypted, it's not really encrypted at all" are hyperbole and incorrect. Thus downvote.

Comment: you are presuming that AWS is a trusted entity.  end-to-end means that keys never leave the end-user's machine; and the cloud never has the key even temporarily.  when the cloud has the key temporarily, that's called "encrypted-at-rest".  for a thought exercise, would you store your heavy metal videos in a Saudi Arabian AWS region while living there?  no, you would not.  that region can intercept your keys when you use them, because it's not end-to-end.  hence, if it's not end-to-end, security rests on assuming that the cloud provider doesn't intercept keys when used.

Comment: you can use gdb to dump the memory of a process.  i have done it already.  you can find keys in memory.